# Report active directory history for new/removed objects

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I've been tasked with finding a way to generate a report to document new desktop\laptop computers that are both joined and removed from Active Directory (Server 2008).

Is there a way to pull a report directly from AD for all systems joined\removed in the last 30 days?  My other alternative is to manually record systems as calls come in and get closed but that could be prone to error and time intensive.

**Disclaimer:**  *I'm not very familiar with reporting features in AD and have limited permissions to control computer objects in AD (add, modify, remove), though once I find the process I'll be giving it to someone else for implementing.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend learning Powershell, but since I know we all have tools we like to use, I'll simply recommend one I use all the time that should cover what you are after:

[AD Info - Active Directory Query Tool](http://www.cjwdev.co.uk/Software/ADReportingTool/Info.html)

I use it all the time, simply because I actually like a GUI and it's easy to use without having to dig up a script or think a lot... :)

I use it to query for any new servers in our environment monthly, but you can get what you need with the free version or buy the full version if you need to like me...

Comment: I found the powershell methods I was looking for.

Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties whenCreated | ? { ((Get-Date) - $_.whenCreated).Days -lt 30} | Format-Table Name,WhenCreated,DistinguishedName -Autosize -Wrap

Get-ADObject -Filter {(isdeleted -eq $true) -and (name -ne "Deleted Objects") -and (ObjectClass -eq "Computer")} -includeDeletedObjects

Copied\pasted from other articles but they do what I need.  I checked out the AD Info tool as well and that also would do exactly what we need it to.